# Java OpenGL Syntax

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, lwjgl, java-package

i am new here and have a little problem.
I included OpenGl into eclipse and tried to run a little test program and everything is working fine as it should, but i have a problem with the syntax.

Here is a little example :

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(45, (float)Display.getWidth()/(float)Display.getHeight(), 0.3f,1000f);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

As far as i remember i didnt have to call the GL version everytime and should look like this :

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(45, (float)Display.getWidth()/(float)Display.getHeight(), 0.3f, 1000f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

I havnt found any answer out there because for everyone it seems to work from scratch. I start to believe that i did a mistake while including opengl into eclipse but i did it like i did it back at university.

[java build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HLfX.png)

Hopefully someone knows what i can do or not do :D

I tried following tutorials on youtube and they all use the second codeblock and even if i follow the same libraries it doesnt work for me while it works in the tutorial ???
I tried different build paths and didnt change anything.
I tried to change the library version but didnt do anything either.

Comment: This is not a problem with OpenGL itself or with the OpenGL API.

Comment: Does this help? `import static fully.qualified.path.GL11.*;`

Answer (score 0):

To reference static methods with qualifying them with the class name, eg `glEnable(x)` instead of `GL11.glEnable(x)`, you must import the static methods, either individually or all of them:

```
import static fully.qualified.path.GL11.*;
```